# prime number theorem and inversion

Tags: number-theory

let be the prime number theorem

$$ \pi (x)= \frac{x}{ln(x)} $$

then if i use wolfram to inver this function

$$ aln(x)-x=0 $$ with $ a=\pi(x)$

i get $$ a==exp(-W(-1/x)) $$

with $ W(x)$ the lambert function

but this does not agree with the fact that $ p_{n}=nlog(n) $

the 'inverse ' of $ \pi(x)$ is just $ p:{n} $ the n-th prime

i tried wolfram alpah http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csolve%7Baln(x)%3Dx%7D

Comment: Why would the inverse give you an integer when you don't consider the function as only taking integers as input?

Comment: What means "does not agree"? Different *formula*? How you know that your expression isn't (asymptotically) equivalent to the other?

Comment: The prime number theorem does not state equality.

Comment: You don;t even need to look at inverses to see this "problem" - if this were the prime number theorem, then $\pi(x)$ would never be an integer when $x$ is an integer.

Comment: Can this LambertW-Ansatz be extended?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I think that the $=$ is simply sloppy writing.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Have you read the question? It only makes sense if you take it to mean exact equality.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac x{\ln x}$ is not equal to $\pi(x)$, it is only an approximation,so its inverse is only approximation of the inverse $\pi^{-1}$.